# q is a 3-cycle and looking at the number of permutations p such that $pqp^-1 = q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Say I have a 3-cycle in $S_n$ let's call it $q$. I am looking at the number of even permutations $p$ there are such that $pqp^{-1}= q$.

My thoughts: 
Every 3-cycle can be written as the product of two cycles and $p$ and $q$ are conjugate if they have the same cyclic structure. So would $|A_n|$ be the number of even permutations $p$ such that $p$ and $q$ are conjugates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not about $p$ and $q$ being conjugate. It's about the number of even permutations that commute with $q$. The conjugate $pqp^{-1}$ is the permutation obtained from $q$ by relabeling its indices with $p$. For this to be $q$, $p$ must cyclically map the three indices in $q$ ($3$ different options for that) and perform some even permutation on the remaining $n-3$ elements. Thus the desired number is $3|A_{n-3}|$.

Comment: Thank you that makes perfect sense